# Running Chrome Dev Tools Snippet From Keyboard

Tags: google-chrome

How do I run Chrome Dev Tools snippets from the keyboard or assign them to shortcut keys?

I'm finding snippets really useful for automating small tasks with javascript and I'd like to trigger them from the keyboard for extra speed. Any idea how?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts

Comment: Almost. I've been through that list a couple of times and couldn't find a quick and easy way to fire snippets. Happy to be pointed in the direction of the correct keys combination.

Comment: I'm using Ctrl/Cmd+O, then typing "!" to show a list of snippets. Select with cursor and Enter. Would still like to get to that point quicker, though (like Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+P for commands)

Answer (score 2):

The key sequence mentioned in the [comment above](https://superuser.com/questions/1251679/running-chrome-dev-tools-snippet-from-keyboard#comment2078761_1251679) using the `!` did not work for me.

Here's what works for me in Chrome 81:

- Ctrl+O
- Type name of snippet
- Enter -> Jumps to the snippet. Cursor is now inside its code area
- Ctrl+Enter -> Execute snippet

Still agree that a command which allows direct execution using `Ctrl+P` would be superior...